# Does github provide host and blog service?

Tags: github

I often see some blogs or applications has github in its domain name. For example:http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/ But I can't find these service on github's homepage. Could you tell me how to set a blog on github? And how to create a Fork Me label on the top-right corner of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you're looking for is here:

- http://pages.github.com/